# Why does my console session keep locking out account?

Tags: windows, active-directory, user-accounts

It's difficult to phrase this question properly. I have a number of accounts that I want the session to be kept alive .i.e. Not lock out after 15 mins. Domain accounts, logging on to Server 2012r2.

I have tried the

1. "Console lock display off timeout = 0 minutes" in Power Management settings.
2. "Interactive Logon: Machine inactivity limit = 0 minutes" in Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options -> Interactive logon: Machine inactivity limit.

I can cause the session to lock after 10 seconds or 1 minute. but if I set it to 0 minutes it locks after 15 minutes

Is there something I could look out for regarding Group Policy updates from higher up causing this or is there a setting I'm unaware of that can keep the session alive?